# Create a calculator from a spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, calculator

I have created two spinners where the user can select a Meal Type and then select a food, (e.g. 'Breakfast' and 'Porridge'). I then need to times the food calories by the weight the user enters in an Edit Text but I am not sure how I do this.

How do I associate my spinner options with a number?

```
public class MainActivity3 extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText num1;
    EditText num2;
    EditText num3;
    EditText num4;
    EditText num5;
    Button btnSave;
    EditText calorieResult;


    public Spinner catspinner, planspinner3, planspinner1, planspinner2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle mbfSplash) {
        super.onCreate(mbfSplash);
        setContentView(R.layout.addmeal);

        chooseCategory();
        chooseBreakfast();
        chooseLunch();
        chooseDinner();
        chooseSnack();
    }

    public void chooseCategory() {

        catspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ducategory, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        catspinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        catspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnClickListener());
    }

    private void chooseBreakfast() {
        planspinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist.add("Porridge-40g/140cal");
        planlist.add("Coffee-10g/10cal");
        planlist.add("Toast-30g/87cal");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
        planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner1.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
    }

    private void chooseLunch() {

        planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist1.add("Salad-50g/40cal");
        planlist1.add("Sandwich-50g/200cal");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist1);
        planAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
    }

    private void chooseDinner() {

        planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist2.add("Curry-100g/400cal");
        planlist2.add("Pasta-40g/160cal");
        planlist2.add("Pizza100g/220cal");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist2);
        planAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter3);
    }

    private void chooseSnack() {
        planspinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist.add("Crisps-30g/70cal");
        planlist.add("Chocolate-100g/210cal");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
        planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner1.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
    }

    public class planOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                                   long id) {

            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            if (pos == 0) {
                chooseBreakfast();
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                chooseLunch();
            } else if (pos == 2) {
                chooseDinner();
            } else if (pos == 3) {
                chooseSnack();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: read object oriented programming

Comment: Let me understand this correctly. There are two `Spinner`s. One that shows the type of breakfast and the other that shows the food. Then there is an `EditText` in which the user enters the weight. And you have to multiply the calories associated with the food by the weight. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this without a code editor so pardon the syntax errors but in general you should use an object to store the assoicated data.  Use a custom adapter for your spinners.  Here is some code to get you started.

You should create an object called Food.

```
public class Food {
int mCalories;
String mName;

public Food(String name, int calories) {
    mName= name;
    mCalories = calories;
    }
}
```

Now you can use a custom array adapter for your spinner.

```
public class FoodArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

private List<Food> mItems;
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;

public FoodArrayAdapter(Context ctx, int resource, List<Food> items) {
    super(activity, resource);
    mItems = items;
    mContext = ctx;
    mResource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //You could use a view holder pattern here, won't really matter for a simple text spinner.
    Food item = mItems.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    if (item != null) {
        textView.setText(food.getName());
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public Food getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
    //or make another view for when the spinner is expanded
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.getSize();
}
}
```

Now just associate your custom adapters with your spinners in your main activity.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.myspinner1);
spinner.setAdapter(new FoodAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
      Food food = (Food) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
      //Do whatever you need to do with selected value.  You have reference to both the food and the calories.
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(    AdapterView<?> parent){

    }
  }
```

);

Comment: You've given me a great start. Thanks! :)